# How to use EJS in Strapi

Tags: templates, ejs, strapi

I tried the official documentation, but this does not work.

https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docs/blob/master/files/views.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guide on How to use EJS with Strapi

- Installed strapi-hook-ejs
- Update the .config/hook.json with

```
...
{
  "ejs": {
    "enabled": true,
    "layout": false,
    "viewExt": "ejs",
    "partial": true,
    "cache": false,
    "debug": true
  }
}
...
```

- Add this to the controller, say *./api/api-name/controllers/api-name.js*

```
module.exports = {
  //GET /index
  index: async (ctx) => {
    ctx.render('home', {title: 'Hello world'});
  }
};
```

- Create a directory views in root folder
- Add your ejs templates in the ./views
- Example ./views/home.ejs

`<%= title %>`

> Side note: In the above example, I have used the "index" in the controller api-name.js file. Make sure your API  *./api/api-name/config/routes.json* point to it.

Comment: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/master/packages/strapi-hook-ejs